# Is the extension $\text{Totally Ramified}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

$(1)$ Let $K/F$ be a finite extension of the local field $F$ of characteristic $0$ obtained by adjoining by the roots of a irreducible monic polynomial to $F$. Is the extension $\text{Totally Ramified}$ ?

I know that adjoining the roots of an Eisenstein polynomial produces $\text{Totally ramified}$ extension.

$(2)$ What is the easiest way to check whether the extension is Totally ramified or not ?

Please help

Comment: It may or may not be totally ramified.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, when will be ?

Comment: If you've chosen your polynomial well, you can read off the ramification properties by looking at the polynomial over the residue field. In particular, if the polynomial is not completely reducible over the residue field, then the extension is not totally ramified.

Comment: @Mathmo123, is the converse hold ?  That means, if a polynomial is reducible in residue field, is the Galois  extension totally ramified ?

Comment: Local fields are $\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{C}$ and the finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\Bbb{F}_p((t))$ (proving so is interesting), the latter two have unramified extensions. Maybe you are thinking to $\Bbb{C}((t))$ whose algebraic closure is $\bigcup_n \Bbb{C}((t^{1/n}))$.

Comment: @reuns, the unramified extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ are obtained by adjoining roots of unity. When will get a Totally ramified finite Galois extension ? I mean which kind of polynomial do the job? e.g., Adding roots of Eisenstein polynomial (in the splitting field) produce totally ramified Galois extension ?

Comment: @mathvision the converse holds if you've chosen your polynomial well, namely if a root of your polynomial generates the ring of integers of $K$. For a counter example, if $p\ne2$ the polynomial $X^2 + p^2$ generates an unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ even though it is reducible mod $p$.

Comment: @Mathmo123, so if a polynomial, in $\mathbb{Q}_p$, has a uniformizer $\pi$ as its root then the Galois extension is totally ramified?

Comment: @Mathmo123, your comment was helpful. But I need to understand the story behind it. You said, (1) if the polynomial is not completely reducible over the residue field, then the extension is not totally ramified. Why is that ? Next, you said,  (2) the converse holds if you've chosen your polynomial well, namely $\text{if a root of your polynomial generates the ring of integers of K.}$ Why is that ? Can you please explain these two facts in two comments. It will help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a local field with residue field $k$ and uniformiser $\pi$. Let $F$ be a finite extension with residue field $k_F$ and uniformiser $\pi_F$. An extension $F/K$ can take one of two flavours:

- If $\pi\mathcal O_F = (\pi_F)^e$, we say the extension is ramified. It is totally ramified if $e = [F:K]$.
- If $\pi\mathcal O_F = (\pi_F)$ is still prime, we say the extension is unramified. In this case, we can choose $\pi_F = \pi$.

In the ramified case, the extension is obtained by adding a new uniformiser of smaller valuation: if we normalise the valuation on $F$ so that $v(\pi_F) = 1$, then $v(\pi) = e$. In the totally ramified case, the residue field $k_F = k$.

In the unramified case, the uniformiser does not change. Instead, the extension is happening on the residue field: $[k_F: k] = [F:K]$.

Now, suppose that $F = K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of the irreducible polynomial $f$. We can always assume that $f$ is monic with integer coefficients. In this case, $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer. Let $\overline \alpha$ be its image in $k_F$. Then $\overline \alpha$ is a root of $f\pmod \pi$. In particular, if $F/K$ is totally ramified, then $k(\overline \alpha) = k$. It follows that $f\pmod \pi$ is completely reducible.

The converse is false in general, as $f$ could be a polynomial like $X^2 + p^2$, and $F(\sqrt{-p^2}) = F(\sqrt{-1})$ is unramified if the residue characteristic is not $2$. The problem here is that the map $\mathcal O_K[\sqrt{-p^2}]\to k_F$ is not surjective: its image is exactly $k$! However, if $\mathcal O_F = \mathcal O_K[\alpha]$, then the map $\mathcal O_K[\alpha]\to k_F$ is surjective. In particular, $k_F = k(\overline \alpha)$. So if $f\pmod \pi$ is completely reducible, then $k_F = k$, so $F$ is totally ramified.

Comment: You said $\text{In this case, we can choose $\pi_F=\pi$}$. Do you mean "the case of unramified  extension "?